# must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make an app with both bottom navigation and tab in a single activity. But when I am trying to put the tab inside the navigation fragment one exception comes.
[I want to design like this with two toolbars one is bottom navigation and other is tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8culq.png)

Please help

**LauncherActivity.java**

```
package com.cornicore.dream11statistics;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);


// Bottom Navigation Start

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListner);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();

// Bottom Navigation

    }


// Bottom Navigation Start
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListner = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    android.support.v4.app.Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch(item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_pointtable:
                            selectedFragment = new PointTableFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_share:
                            selectedFragment = new ShareFragment();
                            break;
                    }


                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };

// Bottom Navigation Start



}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
    package com.cornicore.dream11statistics;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements Tab1.OnNavFragmentInteractionListener,Tab2.OnNavFragmentInteractionListener,Tab3.OnNavFragmentInteractionListener {



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


        final ViewPager viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });



        return v;
    }

    public void onNavFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }


}
```

**Tab1.java**

```
package com.cornicore.dream11statistics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Tab1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    WebView webView;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Tab1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Tab1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Tab1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Tab1 fragment = new Tab1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.OnNavFragmentInteractionListener(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
         void OnNavFragmentInteractionListener(Uri uri);

    }

    public interface OnNavFragmentInteractionListener {
    }


    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */



}
```

Error:

```
05-15 11:12:18.862 4926-4926/com.cornicore.dream11statistics E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cornicore.dream11statistics, PID: 4926
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.cornicore.dream11statistics.LauncherActivity@c71a909 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
        at com.cornicore.dream11statistics.Tab1.onAttach(Tab1.java:93)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1363)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1109)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:996)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:99)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2364)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2645)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2136)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1248)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6064)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
```

---

**Viewpager**

```
final ViewPager viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: See inside  `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());` what context you are using to bind the fragment. You need to have `HomeFragment.java` context.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am a beginner. Can you please explain this

Comment: Post your viewpager code

Comment: Posted in the answer section..please check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in this case you should implement your listener in your activity not in  a fragment.

```
public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

This is because Context passed in your fragment comes from activity and not fragment.

If you want HomeFragment to receive events. What you can do is create public setter method for listeners in Tab-fragments.

```
public void setInteractionListener(OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener){
  this.mListener = mListener;
}
```

Comment: works for me...thank you boss

Answer (score 0):

As per this part in your code

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
```

It seems you are passing context which is not an instance of `OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am a beginner. Can you please explain this

Comment: why down-vote ?