# Cannot transition to fragment. Function expecting different type

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create a fragment which will cover half of an activity. I have created the dummy XML, but I cannot transition to it. I have created the fragment through New -> Fragment -> Fragment(Blank). I have not edited the code of the created fragment class, only the XML.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="90pt"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MenuFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BLA"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BLA"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BLA"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BLA"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        />



</LinearLayout>
```

This is where I want to transition to the fragment. It should be done through a button click.

```
findViewById(R.id.Menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Menu fragment goes here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, menuFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
    });
```

This is the problem:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 
'com.example.pogolemotoproektce.MenuFragment', required: 
'android.app.Fragment' less... 
Inspection info:
replace
(int,
 android.app.Fragment)
in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied
to
(int,
com.example.pogolemotoproektce.MenuFragment)
```

occurring on the following line:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, menuFragment);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supposed to use support library, since it's recommended.

Just replace this line :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
```

With:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

And mind the `imports` at the top (remove the wrong import, and replace it with proper one, depending whether you use `androidx` or not, it might differ).
This is how it should be if you're using `androidx`:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: This solved the error, but a new compile time error is thrown now. It is from the automatically created function onAtach(). It throws a RunTimeException stating that it must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: That's something completely different. That has to do with your `MenuFragment` class. Check the code in it and you'll see that the wizzard you used "New->Fragment->Blank Fragment" has given you options (checkboxes) to include some code. That code is throwing the error. You can get rid of it. But that's unrelated to this error.

Comment: I solved it by following the steps of the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343335/must-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener-error-in-android-studio